# How do I programmatically generate a shapefile with python?

Tags: python, d3.js, shapefile

Ultimately, I am looking to run the shapefile through a geo converter like ogr2ogr and yield coordinates which I can then feed to d3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: already had a look at http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/? (Fiurst hit when googling "python shapefile")

Comment: Thanks that was useful Gecco.